# Icon/Symbol to Represent "Done"?

Tags: icons, usability, symbols, semiotics

I have a quiz-based application where users can leaf between questions and select answers. When they're done, there's a "done" button they click.

[image: Windows version of my Android app]

I don't really have polished graphics skills, so I may be additionally limited to using one of these: http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=iconset%3Aorb or trying to photoshop my own version of one of them.

But really, that's a side point; I'm more interested in a graphical symbol for done. I don't want a button that says "done" :)

Also, I'm okay with a semi-intuitive symbol, because I will confirm with the user that they're really done and not going to change their mind.

**Edit:** Thanks for all the great feedback. Here's the updated image post-UX-question:

[image: Thanks, UX.SE!]

Comment: will there also be a completion progress indicator? (eg. "answered 6 of 17 questions")

Comment: You could simply have empty spheres (the above with no checkmark) and light them up clearly to indicate when a question is done to avoid the checkmark thing. That way it looks "filled in"

Comment: And why not include a label? Are they too scary?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan (perceived) lack of real-estate. I'm okay with a small amount of learning on top of decent icons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Not ideal without a label, but it might work for you.

If this is the only button on the page, you might be able to pull it off. After all, most users do not read the labels of buttons they click.

Comment: Checks are particularly clear as "done" symbols (as opposed to meaning "correct") when an empty box is displayed on unfinished items.

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot. The problem is that I'm already using a checkmark to indicate "which answer do you think is the right answer?". If I change "Done" to a checkmark, what do I do about this?

Comment: @ashes999, use radio buttons instead of images.

Comment: @Emil radio buttons are harder due to technical reasons. This is why I don't even have captions on my buttons, but instead, straight image buttons.

Comment: @ashes999, use images of actual radio buttons. Users understand how to use them, and the interface will feel less cluttered.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've uploaded a screenshot of the "after"; it looks much better!

Answer (score 1):

I use a checkmark (like "V"). If done questions have a different color then the icon should have the same color as a done question.

Comment: +1 I like the colour coordination idea. It's very subtle.

Comment: Take a look at the "after" screenshot; is that what you  meant?